# How do I let IPE add rows to the layout?

Tags: 7, panels

I have a site based on AdaptiveTheme with Panel nodes being edited using the In-Place-Editor, because my users want to dynamically arrange their content on their respective Panel nodes.

They especially want to be able to arbitrarily change amounts and orders of columns and rows (not their measures, though). Hence, they e.g. want to be able to do sth like this:

- Row1
  -- Col1 (50%): Content ABC, Col2 (50%): Content DEF
- Row2
  -- Col1 (100%): Content GHI
- Row3
  -- Col1 (33%): Content JKL, Col2 (33%): Content MNO, Col3 (33%): Content PQR
- Row4
  -- Col1 (100%): Content STU

Now they want to use the IPE's WYSIWYG functionality to reorganize the whole thing into e.g.:

- Row1
  -- Col1 (100%): Content DEF
- Row2
  -- Col1 (50%): Content JKL, Col2 (50%): Content MNO
- Row3
  -- Col1 (100%): Content GHI
- Row4
  -- Col1 (50%): Content ABC, Col2 (50%): Content PQR
- Row5
  -- Col1 (100%): Content STU

The problem now is that the responsive Panels layouts are extremely restricted just by their fix number of rows.

I could provide them with the possibilty of using a flexible layout (the layout builder), but

- that's not supported by the responsive AdaptiveTheme Panels integration
- it's not the true WYSIWYG feeling provided by the IPE
- its whole workflow is not exactly user friendly (add column > add row > add region > add content)

What I have in mind would be some sort of extension of the IPE, providing the possibilty of adding/removing/moving rows to the layout - to be picked out of a predefined set (like 100, 50/50, 33/33/33).

Has anyone got an idea how to achieve this perhaps with already existing modules? I'm not stick to Panels if there's anything else which basically does what I need..

Anyway, if someone's got an idea how to extend Panels/IPE, like where to start/a basic concept, I'd love them to share that with me..

*** EDIT ***

I found a better summary of the problem description: what im looking for, is a visual WYSIWYG tool for dynamically changing both rows and columns.
The Panels IPE only lets you manage columns within a predefined structure of rows. And the layout builder doesn't correspond to the WYSIWYG concept.